# How to work with BaseListSyntax, Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Need to add inherite to some interface using roslyn.
I describe the class, but don't know how to set inherite in the following structures:

```
ClassDeclarationSyntax lClassDeclarationSyntax =
Syntax.ClassDeclaration(
                    Syntax.List<AttributeListSyntax>(lAttributeListSyntax), 
                    Syntax.TokenList(lTokens), 
                    Syntax.Identifier(_classInfo.Identifier.ValueText), 
                    null,
                    null,---------
                    Syntax.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(), 
                    Syntax.List<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(lMemberDeclarationSyntaxList));
```

Isolated "null" it is a place for List attributes by type     BaseListSyntax, where i can specify the name of the inherited interface.
How i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like: `Syntax.BaseList(Syntax.ParseTypeName("MyBaseType")` in place of the `null` above.

Comment: Error: cannot convert from 'Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.TypeSyntax' to 'Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SeparatedSyntaxList<Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.TypeSyntax>'

Comment: I create list      `SeparatedSyntaxList<TypeSyntax> lSeparatedSyntaxList = new SeparatedSyntaxList<TypeSyntax>();`and then add the needed element    `TypeSyntax type = Syntax.ParseTypeName("MyInterface");
                lSeparatedSyntaxList.Add(type);`  but list is emty, who knows why?

Comment: SeparatedSyntaxList is immutable, so the call to add returns a new list with the item.aded.  It doesn't add it in place.