# How i can add parameters to method using roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Need add input parameters to method.
I create new instance with type MethodDeclarationSyntax:

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax lMethodDeclarationSyntax = Syntax.MethodDeclaration(
                Syntax.List<AttributeListSyntax>(), 
                Syntax.TokenList(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)), 
                Syntax.IdentifierName("MemoryStream"), 
                null, 
                Syntax.Identifier("Serialize"), 
                null, 
                Syntax.ParameterList(), 
                Syntax.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(), 
                Syntax.Block(lList));
```

How i can add input parameter like a

```
(MyType lMyType)?
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `System.ParameterList()` in your example above, actually construct a parameter list with parameters in it.

Comment: The same way you did when you created a base type list in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833273/how-to-work-with-baselistsyntax-roslyn.  Use the Syntax.* factory methods.